# Read nested json info

Tags: python, json

I have the following json file, which is really big. I need to access the info of the biography.

I tried the following. But it's not working. Seems to be too nested.

```html
for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
            print(data["biography"])
```

JSON:

```
{
    "graphql": {
        "user": {
            "biography": "this is the biography“,
            "blocked_by_viewer": false,
            "connected_fb_page": null,
            "country_block": false,
            "edge_follow": {
                "count": 100
            },
            "edge_followed_by": {
                "count": 100
            },
```

How can I get the info of the biography?

Comment: `data['graphql']['user']['biography']`.

Comment: Perfect. So easy. I was thinking too complicated! Thanks!